# request.getSession().setAttribute() runs on Tomcat but fail Weblogic

Tags: java, session, tomcat, weblogic

I am trying to migrate a Java application from Apache Tomcat to WebLogic. 
I didn't have any problem in Tomcat, but when I deploy and test in Weblogic I have a problem when I use this sentence:

```
UserData user= (UserData)request.getSession().getAttribute("user");
```

I get user = null in Weblogic and in Tomcat I get the correct data.
I was looking about Session Scopes in Weblogic and parameters about configuration on weblogic.xml file, but didn't find any information for my problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I had an text error here, I fix it. I mean getAttribute("user"); Thanks

Comment: Did you set it to session, before getting? If yes,how did you set?

Comment: I use session.setAttribute("user", user);

Answer (score 0):

It all depends upon what is actually in the session, and any number of factors affect that.

Does your application set an attribute called `"user"` into the session? When, and why? Did you make those things happen in Weblogic, just like you did when you were testing on Tomcat?

I would be very surprised if Weblogic has a bug in it where values in a session just disappear for some reason. Someone would have noticed and it would have gotten fixed.

Comment: Yes, i set the "user" attribute. I set in an action previous than this action.
The same code works in Tomcat, but don't  works in Weblogic.

Comment: @RafaelVivas how are we to know about previous actions if you don't provide full reproducable example? the line you've given won't work by itself in *any* server.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. 
I ran the application in diferents Weblogic Servers (Development and Testing servers).
In Test Server the application runs OK. I compare the configurations in bothn servers and i found this diference: "-d64 -Xms128m -Xmx256m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=192m" in Args to Server Begin in Test Server. I changed that parameters in my development server, and the application runs correctly now.
I don't understand yet what is the implication of this parameters in my applications, but i should investigate.
The important thing for now is that my applications runs properly.
Thanks to all.